# Error in Display Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I get this error message when try to display a map using MapView in my project. I had sign up the Map API v1 key for long time, and I also used my fingerprint to re-generate the apikey, but still I get an error message ": **Couldn't get connection factory client**".

Here are my development environment:
android ver.:2.3.3
jre:1.6

Below code also included in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>       
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

[I would like to know what is wrong because the project is actually an example code in my books, which can be downloaded [here][1] - title is "Chap8-Where Am I 4".](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html)

```
W/System.err(10003): IOException processing: 26
java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
```

Comment: You somehow screwed up with the API key. Maybe if you post exactly how you did it, and how you're using it in your code that we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out already. Is the problem of the API key I used. Thanks for your replied.